# Unable to boot Win 7 from DVD on HP Notebook

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have an HP Pavillion notebook. When i bought it Win 10 was already installed by HP. 
Then i also installed a dual-boot Ubuntu.

When my laptop starts it compares Grub that let me choose beetween ubuntu and Win 10.
Now i want to completely wipe my notebook and install win 7.
I have a working win 7 dvd-rom, but the notebook doesn't let me boot from cd.

The problem is that, if i try to change BIOS settings (= the boot's order) , the bios automatically get back to previous values. I don't know if it's due to Grub or to Win 10.

At the moment, Legacy support is enabled and the cd-rom drive works correctly.

Comment: How is that related to Ubuntu? Either the CD (does windows 7 fit on a CD???) is broken or you are not doing it correcly from your BIOS. But I/we do not know what it takes to boot a Windows CD. Either you need to press a key combo during boot or pick the CD from the boot options in your BIOS.

Comment: Yes, but the dvd rom doesn't appear. Maybe it's due to GRUB ( Ubuntu boot manager), since i was able to install Ubuntu via dvd

Comment: Nope. If you see grub you are already too late pressing the key to either boot from the media or getting into BIOS.  Installing another OS does not require the current OS (ie. you can wipe the drive and would still be able to boot from a DVD).

Answer (score 1):

The selection of a boot device (hard drive vs optical drive vs USB flash drive vs PXE LAN boot) must be made before you get to a boot manager such as GRUB.

With an HP system, as soon as you press the power-on button, immediately begin hitting the **Esc** button (like tap-tap-tap) - like press and begin hitting before any logo appears.  Soon, you will be presented a list of boot options; press  **F9**  for a one-time boot option, and your optical drive will appear if that drive sees a good disk.